# What is be the best way to code selecting mode as Windows using javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

You can select a folder in windows when you clic on a folder once..

I'm working with Vuejs. I would like to code the same thing with multiple arrays i get from my database and exposed with **`v-for`**

What i'm thinking about, is to add a new column (select) to each array with default `value  = 0`. Then i can apply a function on-click on each array to change it's select value to `value = 1` and i can also add a css class to distinct the selected element (Blue border color).

**At this moment, my element with column select `value = 1` it the selected one.**

It becomes more complicated when you want to change the selection (Select another array). I need first to make all columns (select) `value = 0`, second, remove all css classes, before restartng the operation. (Because only one element must be selected)

Any advices ?  Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pretty trivial with Vue.js. You do not need anything special like column or so. You just need to set your `ViewModel` correctly. Your template would be:

```
<div>
  <!-- Note the use of dynamic :class bindings -->
  <div v-for="folder in list" class="folder-item" :key="folder.id"
    @click="onClick(folder)"
    :class="{ 'folder-item__active': folder === selected }">
      <span>{{ folder.folderName }}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And your component's JavaScript would be:

```
Vue.extend({

  data() {
    return {
      // Initial list of folders
      list: [
        { folderName: 'Folder 1', id: 1 /* Some more data */ },
        { folderName: 'Folder 2', id: 1 /* Some more data */ },
      ],

      // Important to set to null for Vue.js to track reactivity
      selected: null
    };
  },

  mounted() {

    // Later on change the folder list
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.list = [/* Some new list */]
      this.selected = null;
    }, 3000);
  },

  methods: {
    onClick(selectedItem) {
      this.selected = selectedItem;
    }
  }
});
```

There are three things to be aware of:

1. Use of dynamic `:class` [bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html).
2. Use of `@click` event handler to keep track of **selected** folder.
3. Whenever you change `list`, simply change `selected` value to `null`. (Internally, comparing references to detect changes is super simple and easy.)

Of course, if your list keep changing due the use of immutable data, then your `active` folder selection logic will fail. In that case, you can rely of some unique identifier and update the code accordingly:

```
<!-- Vue binding -->
:class="{ 'folder-item__active': folder.id === selected && selected.id }"
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but where and when do you define selectedItem ?

Comment: @yassinej, when onClick is called, Vue will inject the clicked item. We are providing it from the template.